# Saving a string with erb data in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently save code like below in my user model.

```
User.where(type: "supercool").each do |user|
    if user.score == 100
        user.message = "Hello #{user.name}, you now have #{user.points} points!".html_safe
    elsif user.address == "New York"
        user.message = "You live in the same town as #{Person.where(address:"New York").first.name}"
    user.save
end
```

I save these messages in my model, and print them out in the view by just calling User.find(params[:id]).messages in the controller.

The actual model code is much longer, as there are many unique messages based on different scenarios.

While this works, I would now like to add a `link_to` to objects that are mentioned in the messages.

For the first message, I want to save it so that when I send it to the view, it's in the form of

```
Hello <%= link_to user.name, user_path(user.id) %>, you now have <%= link_to user.points, leaderboard_path %> points!
```

I tried the below, but it doesn't work.

```
User.where(type: "supercool").each do |user|
    if user.score == 100
        user.message = "Hello #{link_to user.name, user}, you now have #{link_to user.points, leaderboard_path} points!".html_safe
    user.save
end
```

How can I save erb in my string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Use html tags instead of using link_to

```
  User.where(type: "supercool").each do |user|
    if user.score == 100
      user.message = "Hello <a href=#{Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_path(user)}>#{user.name}</a>, you now have <a href=#{Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.leaderboard_path}>#{user.points}</a> points!".html_safe
      user.save
   end
 end
```

And in your view, Just do

```
<%= user.message %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very good pratice.

You can like:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def example
    ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to user.name, user
  end 
end
```

But using a helper or a erb template to show this to the user seems the best way.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. The reason I don't want to use a helper or erb template is because there are a lot of different scenarios, each with different links. It seems like I would have to pass a lot of logic from the model to the helper, thereby increasing complexity. Or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: Hi umezo, I really think that these messages that you show to the user should be on the views/helpers. Or maybe you can use decorator pattern to do this. Keeping this on the model, and specially on database would bring problems later, like if you change the paths in the future. Check out some stuff about the decorator pattern with rails, and you will find that it is kind of what you want.